# Multinomial theorem for derivative of product of many functions

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, derivatives, multinomial-theorem

I just learnt The Leibnitz rule for nth derivative of product of two functions,
Can you please explain the same for nth derivative of n functions?
An example for nth derivative of 3 functions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read what e.g. Wikipedia has to say about it? A more specific question ("I've read X but I don't understand step Y / detail Z") will generally get a more useful answer.

Comment: From a combinatorial perspective we may think of our functions as labelled bins and successive derivatives as labelled balls to be placed in them. So $(uvw)'=u'vw+uv'w+uvw'$ says that the first ball may be placed in bin $u$ ($u'vw$) or bin $v$ ($uv'w$) or bin $w$ ($uvw'$). So the $u^{(a)}v^{(b)}w^{(c)}$ term in $(uvw)^{(n)}$ (where $n=a+b+c$) will occur every time $a$ labelled balls are placed in bin $u$, $b$ in bin $v$ and $c$ in bin $w$, there are therefore $(a+b+c)!/(a!b!c!)$ such terms and so this is the coefficient. I hesitate to answer as I don't know if this is what you are after.